# How do I store input in my python discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a discord bot where you can get a random number with the max being what you type. Like this:

```
number = input("")

number = int(number)

print(random.randint(1, number))
```

But my problem is storing the input the user typed. All I've done this far is making it only certain max numbers like 2 and 100.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content == ("r100"):
    await message.channel.send(random.randint(1, 100))

  if message.content == ("r2"):
    await message.channel.send(random.randint(1, 2))
```

Comment: You can do ```number = int(input(""))```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `max_random= int(message.content[1:])` to get the number after the `"r"`:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  max_random = int(message.content[1:])
  await message.channel.send(random.randint(1, max_random))
```

Comment: `max` is a reserved keyword in python (already a function), you should use another name

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is with a [`commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) [`Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command)

you can set different parameters to a command, and can convert them super easy

```py
from discord.ext import commands  # import commands

# instead of client = discord.Client()
client = discord.Client()
# use this
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
```

remove the on_message event, or add [client.process_commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) to it

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message) # add this line
    # you can also add other stuff here
```

```py
# add a command
@client.command()
async def random(ctx, max_number: int): 
    await ctx.send(f"Your number is: {random.randint(1, max_number)}")


# you can also add a second arg
@client.command()
async def random2(ctx, min_number: int, max_number: int): 
    await ctx.send(f"Your number is: {random.randint(min_number, max_number)}")
```

to use the command you can type `!random 50` or `!random2 20 50`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but it did not work out as I wanted (fixed it how I want it now)

Answer (score 0):

The code Chuaat posted helped me but with that you could type (for example) 101 and it would say 1. I got to a solution to put it like this instead:

```
if message.content.startswith("r"):
    maxnum = int(message.content[1:])
    await message.channel.send(random.randint(1, maxnum))
```

The mistake I made when trying to do exactly this was putting == after startswith.